# Are there any advantage for passing closure to a method?

Tags: methods, groovy, closures

I wonder what is the real use of passing a closure object to a method.

Lets say I have a closure :

```
def a = {
        println it
 }
```

(Consider it is doing some sort of operation rather than just printing)

Now I'm just passing this closure `a` to a method :

```
def testMethod(def input,Closure a){
        a(input)
}

testMethod "MethodPointer", a //passing closure.
```

Now the question is why this level of *indirection*? Why can't `testMethod` directly process  its `input`? Yes, here I'm making `input` to be processed in closure `a`, but why one should do so?. What is the real use of passing closure around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How would you write the `collect` method without `Closures` for parameters?  It would be a lot more complex than it is currently.  The same goes for Builders, `inject`, `each`, `with` and many more...

It allows you to define something generic, and then make it more specific at a later date.  For example, the `collect` method could be described as *"takes a collection or iterable, and for each element DO SOMETHING and add it to a newly created collection"*.  Without Closures to specify this *DO SOMETHING* at a later date, the value of `collect` would be minimal.

Slowly, you come to a more functional way of thinking.  Rather than writing a specific function to perform a specific task, could I write a function which takes more of a generalist approach applicable to multiple problems, and put the specifics for each individual case in a Closure?

---

#### Edit

As an example, consider this procedural method which returns a List of the numbers between `min` and `max` which are multiples of `mult`:

```
List<Integer> filter( int min, int max, int mult ) {
  List<Integer> multiples = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
  for( int i = min ; i < max ; i++ ) {
    if( i % mult == 0 ) {
      multiples.add( i ) ;
    }
  }
  multiples
}

println filter( 1, 200, 15 )
```

If we write this in Groovy using Closures (for the filtering), we get:

```
List<Integer> filter( int min, int max, int mult ) {
  (min..max).findAll { it % mult == 0 }
}

println filter( 1, 200, 15 )
```

(I accept that this example is basically mirroring the functionality of `findAll`, so probably isn't a great example -- and is also somewhat contrived)

Now consider that we want to filter based on some other criteria (that the integer exists in a database or something)...  We could first rewrite our `filter` method to:

```
List<Integer> filter( int min, int max, Closure<Boolean> filter ) {
  (min..max).findAll filter
}

println filter( 1, 200 ) { it % 15 == 0 }
```

Then, as you can see, we can pass any closure to this method that returns true if we want to keep the element, or false if we want to drop it.

To do this in an imperative style, you're going to (probably) end up with multiple methods all doing very similar tasks...

Comment: So this sort of coding is basically similar to function pointer in C??

Comment: @batman yeah, similar -- one difference I can think of is that  closures have their own scope and binding, and I'm not sure you can dynamically create functions and return pointers to them in C -- I may be wrong though...

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to write modular and structured clear code.

I wrote a blog post about [Closure Design Patterns](http://arturoherrero.com/2012/04/25/closure-design-patterns/). You can find some examples of patterns using closures.